# transform number with commas in number without commas

Tags: javascript

How could I transform a number with commas like 123,245  to a number without commas like this 123245, I know that you could already put commas in number without them but how to do that in reverse?
 pure JAVASCRIPT please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var number = Number("123,456".split(",").join(""));
```

Or:

```
var number = parseInt("123,456".split(",").join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using a regex `/,/g`

```js
console.log("123,245".replace(/,/g, ''));
console.log("123,245,566".replace(/,/g, ''));
```